# Проблема с выводом данных в формате JSON в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой вывода в формате JSON в NodeJS. Может я как-то не так это делаю? Формирую объект prod собирая данные из массива its. Здесь вывод в формат JSON делается правильно, для каждого объекта (смотреть первые 2 строки вывода - данные разные). После того как с помощью метода push я записываю эти данные в объект _receipt в свойство Items через цикл for, JSON выдает мне одинаковые данные.

```
var _receipt = {
   Email: "email",
   Phone: "phone",
   Taxation: "tax_info"
};

// Получить массив элементов из карточки
var its = cart.generateArray();

var prod = {};
_receipt.Items = [];

// Заполнить объект prod
for (var id in its){
   prod.Name = its[id].item.title;
   prod.Price = its[id].item.price;
   prod.Quantity = its[id].qty;
   prod.Amount = prod.Quantity * prod.Price;
   prod.Tax = "tax_info";
   _receipt.Items.push(prod); // записать в _receipt.Items
   console.log(JSON.stringify(prod));
}

console.log('-----');
console.log(_receipt);
console.log('-----');
var receipt = JSON.stringify(_receipt);
console.log(receipt);
```

Вывод:

```
{"Name":"Name1","Price":3400,"Quantity":2,"Amount":6800,"Tax":"tax_rate"}
{"Name":"Name2","Price":5500,"Quantity":1,"Amount":5500,"Tax":"tax_rate"}
-----
{ Email: 'email',
  Phone: 'phone',
  Taxation: 'tax_info',
  Items:
  [ { Name: 'Name1',
      Price: 5500,
      Quantity: 1,
      Amount: 5500,
      Tax: 'vat0' },
    { Name: 'Name2',
      Price: 5500,
      Quantity: 1,
      Amount: 5500,
      Tax: 'vat0' } ] }
-----
{
 "Email":"email",
 "Phone":"phone",
 "Taxation":"tax_info",
 "Items":
 [{
   "Name":"Name1",
   "Price":5500,
   "Quantity":1,
   "Amount":5500,
   "Tax":"tax_rate"
  },
  {
   "Name":"email",
   "Price":5500,
   "Quantity":1,
   "Amount":5500,
   "Tax":"tax_rate"
  }]
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ошибка вот здесь:

```
var prod = {};
```

Вы создаёте один объект, и в цикле меняете ему свойства. И помещаете в массив одну и ту же ссылку на объект *prod*. В итоге в массиве будет сколько угодно одинаковых ссылок с таким объектом, каким он получился на последнем витке цикла.

Чтобы это исправить, вам нужно создавать **новый объект** каждый раз перед помещением в массив **на каждой итерации цикла**, так в массив будут попадать разные объекты с уникальными ссылками.

Это всё особенность JavaScript с его динамической природой, например, если вы сделаете так,

```js
let A = { q: 'to be!' };
let B = A;
B.q = 'not to be!';

console.log(A);
```

то в результате получите то, что объект **A** изменился вместе с объектом **B** (что может показаться неожиданным), так как они *ссылаются* на один и тот же объект в памяти.

Если вам нужно избежать такого поведения в случае создания объекта не с нуля, а из другого объекта, то вам уже следует использовать `Object.assign({}, someObject)` (но это не единственный возможный вариант).

Для вашего примера исправленный вариант:

```js
var _receipt = {
   Email: "email",
   Phone: "phone",
   Taxation: "tax_info"
};

// Получить массив элементов из карточки
var its = {
  0: {"Name":"Name1","Price":3400,"Quantity":2,"Amount":6800,"Tax":"tax_rate"},
  1: {"Name":"Name2","Price":5500,"Quantity":1,"Amount":5500,"Tax":"tax_rate"}
};

_receipt.Items = [];

// Заполнить объект prod
for (let id in its) {
  let prod = {};
  prod.Name = its[id].Name;
  prod.Price = its[id].Price;
  prod.Quantity = its[id].Quantity;
  prod.Amount = prod.Quantity * prod.Price;
  prod.Tax = "tax_info";
  _receipt.Items.push(prod); // записать в _receipt.Items
  console.log(JSON.stringify(prod));
}

console.log('-----');
console.log(_receipt);
console.log('-----');
var receipt = JSON.stringify(_receipt);
console.log(receipt);
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ!)

Comment: Пожалуйста! :) Спасибо за хороший вопрос)